# Issue in sharing my website post to facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I am using JavaScript SDK to implement feed functionality. Here is my problem, if a user is logged-in and clicked on share button, Facebook is able to see the post in the timeline, but it is not reflecting in home page.
How can I solve this?
I am using this code -

```
FB.init({appId: "XXXXXXXXX",show_error:true, status: true, cookie: true}); 

function postToFeed() { 

  // calling the API ... 
  var obj = { 
    method: 'feed', 
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/', 
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg', 
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs', 
    caption: 'Reference Documentation', 
    description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.' 
  }; 

  FB.ui(obj, callback); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't decide what appears on the homepage.  It depends on the users settings and on how Facebook decides to promote certain types of content.

The homepage is just a condensation of all your friend's/subscription's/page's timelines'.  When you share a URL - you share it on **your** timeline and never share it to the homepage.

**This is the expected behavior.**

---

If your application posts something to a users timeline, it is most likely that his/her friends **will** see it on their homepage but there is currently no way to ensure this.  Take for example a situation where one of your users share's a URL but their friends only come into Facebook 2 days later - you can't expect that story to still appear on their homepage after so much time has passed.  Like I said - it is likely going to appear on the homepage at some stage - but you have no control over that.

Comment: can u suggest any one of facebook API which can overcome this porblem?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I can not.  This is a limitation with working with Facebook.  The one thing I think would always bring a story to the homepage is if it has "likes" on it.  If one or more people "like" the story, Facebook will show it to more people. *This is of course a guess - I have no real clue how Facebook decides what to place on the homepage.*